# How can I create Yugabyte Job for my Stored-procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, cron-task, yugabytedb

In Oracle, we can create JOBs and configure them to run every 2 hours / every morning / etc. as per project requirement.
Does Yugabyte also support such JOBs - i.e. periodic automatic re-execution of stored-procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Internal cron jobs aren't available by default in PostgreSQL & YugabyteDB.
You have to execute the cron job outside the database.

There is [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension for PostgreSQL though we haven't tested it with YugabyteDB.